# How to find the resistor using the equivalent resistance?

Tags: resistors

How would I simplify this circuit so I can find the missing resitors using equivalent resistance?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the circuit into simpler components. As an initial step, replace the  3 R's in parallel with R/3 resistor. Re-draw it and then simplify and then proceed in similar fashion.

Comment: When I redrew it the result that I came out was  Rab=12+(25(60+R))/28 but I do not believe that is right.

Comment: No, I don't think your expression for Rab is correct. Post your steps on how you arrived at the answer. You must get the variable R in both numerator as well as denominator as the parallel combination of 3 R's along with15 and 20 Ohm are again in parallel with 10 Ohm

Comment: It's wrong and that should be obvious. If R-> infinity, then the resistance must go to 22 ohms, by inspection. If R->0 then the resistance goes to 19.78 ohms.

Comment: So 20ohms and R/3 are in series, aren't 15 and 10 also in series? Then does that not make those two parallel to each other?

Comment: R/3 is in series with 20 and 15. Combine these three three and re-draw the circuit on a paper. This combination (R/3+20+15) is in parallel with 10 Ohms

Comment: @Rafael: No, 15 and 10 are NOT in series as the 12 resistor inserts some current into the middle node (when someting is connected to the input, obviously) that "breaks" the voltage divider.

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier,  replace those three parallel R resistors with R/3,  then see,  R/3 and 20 resistor are in series,  so replace them by (R/3+20),then observe 12,15,10 are in star,  so perform a delta conversion. Rest should be easy.